# fread(): reading table with \r\r\n as newline symbol

Tags: r, performance, data.table, line-endings

I have tab-delimited tables in text files where all lines end with `\r\r\n` (`0x0D 0x0D 0x0A`). If I try to read such file with `fread()`, it says

> Line ending is \r\r\n. R's download.file() appears to add the extra \r
>   in text mode on Windows. Please download again in binary mode
>   (mode='wb') which might be faster too. Alternatively, pass the URL
>   directly to fread and it will download the file in binary mode for
>   you.

but I am not downloading these files, I already have them.

So far I came to the solution which first reads the file with `read.table()` (it treats `\r\r\n` combination as a single end-of-line character), then converts resulting `data.frame` by `data.table()`:

```
mydt <- data.table(read.table(myfilename, header = T, sep = '\t', fill = T))
```

but I am wondering if there's any way to avoid slow `read.table()` and use fast `fread()` instead.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using the GNU utility `tr` to get rid of those unnecessary `\r` characters.  e.g.

```
cat("a,b,c\r\r\n1, 2, 3\r\r\n4, 5, 6", file = "test.csv")
fread("test.csv")
## Error in fread("test.csv") : 
##  Line ending is \r\r\n. R's download.file() appears to add the extra \r in text mode on Windows. Please download again in binary mode (mode='wb') which might be faster too. Alternatively, pass the URL directly to fread and it will download the file in binary mode for you.

system("tr -d '\r' < test.csv > test2.csv")
fread("test2.csv")
##    a b c
## 1: 1 2 3
## 2: 4 5 6
```

If you are using Windows and do not have the `tr` utility, you can get it [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

**Added:**

I did some comparisons of three methods, using a 100,000 x 5 sample cvs dataset.

- `OPcsv` is the "slow" `read.table` method
- `freadScan` is a method that discards the extra `\r` characters in pure R
- `freadtr` calls GNU `tr` through the shell using `fread()` directly.

The third method is by far the fastest.

```
# create a 100,000 x 5 sample dataset with lines ending in \r\r\n
delim <- "\r\r\n"
sample.txt <- paste0("a, b, c, d, e", delim)
for (i in 1:100000) {
    sample.txt <- paste0(sample.txt,
                        paste(round(runif(5)*100), collapse = ","),
                        delim)
}
cat(sample.txt, file = "sample.csv")


# function that translates the extra \r characters in R only
fread2 <- function(filename) {
    tmp <- scan(file = filename, what = "character", quiet = TRUE)
    # remove empty lines caused by \r
    tmp <- tmp[tmp != ""]
    # paste lines back together together with \n character
    tmp <- paste(tmp, collapse = "\n")
    fread(tmp)
}

# OP function using read.csv that is slow
readcsvMethod <- function(myfilename)
    data.table(read.table(myfilename, header = TRUE, sep = ',', fill = TRUE))

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OPcsv = readcsvMethod("sample.csv"),
               freadScan = fread2("sample.csv"),
               freadtr = fread("tr -d \'\\r\' < sample.csv"),
               unit = "relative")
## Unit: relative
##           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##          OPcsv 1.331462 1.336524 1.340037 1.365397 1.366041 1.249223   100
##      freadScan 1.532169 1.581195 1.624354 1.673691 1.676596 1.355434   100
##        freadtr 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but ideally I would like to find a way without using external utilities (and yes, I'm under Windows).

Comment: OK, I added an R-only method plus comparisons. See edited answer.

Comment: You can put that system call into `fread()`.  Do `fread("cat test.csv | tr -d '\r'")` and you can skip the `system()` step, similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499145/preventing-column-class-inference-in-fread/29499512#29499512).  The quotes around `\r` may not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven, I had just figured out that the `fread()` can take shell commands directly. But it didn't work for me without quotes around the `\r`.

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer good tip, it should be added though that not only the quotes seem to be necessary you also need to double escape the backslash i.e. `fread("cat f.csv | tr - d '\\r'")`. That was the only way I got it to work on Linux